# Unable to get Xdebug working with Lando and VSCode. Connects and stops immediately

Tags: visual-studio-code, configuration, xdebug, lando

I have been through every post I can find on this subject but I can not find a solution. So instead of pulling my hair out more, I'll post a question.

I have a Lando install (running Drupal 8, but I'm testing on a simple `phpinfo()` script) with Xdebug confirmed to be running. Whenever I add a breakpoint and run the script it fails to stop.

custom Lando .ini for Xdebug:

```
[PHP]

Xdebug
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 256
xdebug.show_exception_trace = 0
xdebug.collect_params = 0
; Extra custom Xdebug setting for debug to work in VSCode.
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = ${LANDO_HOST_IP}
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 0
xdebug.remote_mode = req
xdebug.remote_autostart = On
xdebug.remote_log = /tmp/xdebug.log
xdebug.idekey = VSCODE

max_execution_time = 0
```

Output of xdebug.log

```
245] Log opened at 2020-09-09 14:42:21
[245] I: Connecting to configured address/port: host.docker.internal:9000.
[245] I: Connected to client. :-)
[245] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///app/web/info.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="7.3.22" protocol_version="1.0" appid="245" idekey="VSCODE"><engine version="2.9.6"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2020 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

[245] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

[245] Log closed at 2020-09-09 14:42:21
```

I had xdebug working without an issue in PhpStorm but no luck in VSCode.

Comment: Try different port (e.g. 9001) in both php.ini and IDE/editor config. The Xdebug log content is typical to what you will see when Xdebug connects to php-fpm instance (that also uses TCP 9000 port by default in most installs): it simply tells Xdebug to just continue running without doing any debugging.

Answer (score 7):

### After the latest [release](https://github.com/lando/lando/releases) v3.0.22**

which includes support for **xdebug 3** you will need the `xdebug: debug` and `config: php` settings in your `.lando.yml`

```yaml
services:
  appserver:
    webroot: web
    xdebug: debug
    config:
      php: .lando.php.ini
```

a `.lando.php.ini` file with

```
[PHP]
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.client_host = ${LANDO_HOST_IP}
xdebug.log = /tmp/xdebug.log
```

and the vscode configuration in `.vscode/launch.json` with `port: 9003`

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Lando XDebug",
      "type": "php",
      "request": "launch",
      "port": 9003,
      "log": false,
      "pathMappings": {
        "/app/": "${workspaceFolder}/",
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

### Before and up to [release](https://github.com/lando/lando/releases) v3.0.19

I was able to run lando xdebug with vscode using this configuration `.vscode/launch.json`

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Lando XDebug",
      "type": "php",
      "request": "launch",
      "port": 9000,
      "log": true,
      "pathMappings": {
        "/app/": "${workspaceRoot}/",
      }
    },
  ]
}
```

and I did not include any lando `php.ini` config in my `.lando.yml`

```yaml
services:
  appserver:
    webroot: web
    xdebug: true
# no need for php.ini configuration
#    config:
#      php: .lando.php.ini
```

that the [official xdebug actually instructs](https://docs.lando.dev/guides/lando-with-vscode.html)

Comment: In my case, I had to force VSC to listen on the port 9003 via IPV4 protocol.

This can be achieved by adding `"hostname": "0.0.0.0"`  to `launch.json`.